# Add docstrings to Ruby language using metaprogramming

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to use metaprogramming to introduce docstring feature into Ruby language.

Here is very early prototype of the code I've written so far:

```
module Docstrings
  def doc(docstring)
    @docstrings ||= {}
    if docstring.is_a? String
      # Ruby 2.0 trick to get a caller of the method
      method_caller = caller_locations(1,1)[0].label.to_sym

      @docstrings[method_caller] ||= docstring
    else
      @docstrings[docstring]
    end
  end
end

# lets include it temporarily to see how it works
include Docstrings

class Method
   include Docstrings
end

doc "Hello"
puts doc :"<main>" # => "Hello"
```

It works. But, sadly:

```
def square(x)
  doc """This method returns square of x"""

  x * x
end

doc(:square) # => nil
```

This is not working as I expected.

```
square(2)
doc(:square) # => """This method returns square of x"""
```

It will add docstring only when method square is invoked at least 1 time which is obvious.

My question is is it possible to implement in a way that a docstring will be attached more to a method, not to invocation of that method? I'm looking for hints not for solution, please tell me where should I look :)

Comment: You're trying to implement something in code that has to be implemented in the interpreter/compiler. It's similar to how a language implements in-line comments; They're processed as the code is initially parsed, not at run-time. That's why `square` has to be "called" at least once.

Comment: Yes, doc is not called until the method is run, so the doc method can't record anything until the method is run. Perhaps you could write a program that reads the source file, locates the docs, and builds your data structure.

Comment: The big problem with this is it can only be implemented in the interpreter/compiler source. Changing the source will only fix it in your copy and make it non-standard. *I* don't want them in my Ruby code because I use `rdoc` and `ri` for my documentation and suspect that's the feeling of the source maintainers.

Comment: I don't want to parse the source file. I wanted to use metaprogramming techniques for this, but now I see that it is no way to do this without messing with interpreter/compiler source code. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work: (Although, it is not really meta-programming and is just a hack)

Let's say you want this:

```
  def add_these(a, b)
    doc "This function adds two numbers"
    a + b
  end

whatsthedocdoc?(:add_these) # => "This function adds two numbers"

class Object
  def whatsthedocdoc?(method)
    meth = method(method.to_sym)
    sours = meth.source
    puts sours.lines.grep(/doc/).join.gsub(/doc|\"/, "").strip
  end
end
```

---

But it is not so simple. The above snippet assumes the methods are defined in the `main` object space. Let's consider the example:

```
class A
  def add_these(a, b)
    doc "This method adds two numbers."
  end
end
```

In this example, the code inside the `whatsthedocdoc?` method should change to:

```
def whatsthedocdoc?(string)
  receiver, meth = string.split(/\#/)
  meth_instance = receiver.method(meth.to_sym)
  sours = meth_instance.source
  # rest is the same as above
end
```

And the documentation can be viewed like so:

```
whatsthedocdoc?("A#add_these") # => This method adds two numbers.
```

Not quite neat now is it?

---

Oh! There is yet another edge-case: A Class method

```
class A
  def self.add_these(a, b)
    doc "This too, adds two numbers"
  end
end
```

You get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

With ruby hook, we can intercept methods definition. So this
solution work, but doc() must be defined before the method def :

```
class Object

    def self.method_added(s)
        @docString||={}
        if defined?(@lastdoc)&& @lastdoc!=""
            @docString[s]=@lastdoc
            @lastdoc=""
        else
            @docString[s]="!uncommented !"
        end
    end
    def self.defdoc(s)
        @lastdoc=s
    end
    ################ report
    def self.get_docs()
        @docString||={}
        puts "Doc for #{self.to_s} is : \n"
        @docString.each  {|k,v|puts " #{k} : #{v}\n"}
        puts "end for #{self.to_s}\n"
    end
    def get_docs(*klass)
        klass.each {|c| c.get_docs()}
    end
end
################# exemple :
class Foo
    defdoc "toto() defined"
    def toto ;end
    def titi ;end
    defdoc "tutu() defined"
    def tutu ;end
    def tata ;end
end
class Fee < Foo
end

get_docs Foo,Fee
```

This give :

```
Doc for Foo is :
 toto : toto() defined
 titi : !uncommented !
 tutu : tutu() defined
 tata : !uncommented !
end for Foo
Doc for Fee is :
end for Fee
```